# Google Analytics spreadsheet Add-on - Filter and sort on main results

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

On google Analytics spredsheet add-on, I am trying to take only top results of a dimension (ga:pagePath), based on the specific metric (ga:pageViews).

I want my top 10 pages (based on the number of pageviews).

How can I do that in the query?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When creating the "report configuration" tab in Google Sheets, then use these dimensions and metrics to create your report: [This is an example Report Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p73yv.png) which displayed my top 10 pages in a report.